# Are the diagonal entries of the S-matrix in 1D equal?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, scattering, linear-algebra

Looking at the [S-matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-matrix) of some potential barrier in one dimension one can show that is has the form
$$
S = \begin{bmatrix} u & v \\ v & w\end{bmatrix}
$$
with $u, v, w \in \mathbb{C}$ satisfying $|u|^2 + |v|^2 = 1$ and $|u| = |w|$. If the potential is symmetric one even has $u = w$. Does this last equality hold in general?